# Hierarchical Forecasting problem generating the hts object

Tags: r, forecasting, forecast

I want to do hierarchical forecasting as described in Hyndman Forecasting's book in chapter 10: https://otexts.com/fpp2/

My problem is that for generating this type of forecasting (specifically the bottom-up approach) I need to develop a hts object that is a matrix. For example:

If I have a data frame like this:
[Image of an example of data frame prior to hts object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJdAy.png)

I need to convert it to a matrix like this:
[Image of Matrix that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kofIj.png)
For this matrix, every row is a unit of time (it could be days, months, etc.).

My problem is that my data frame looks like this:
[Image of Problem with dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hlMM.png)

One column is the date and the other are the categories from which I need to forecast the sales. The problem is this: for supermarket=4, id_product=187, and id_label=a the system registers movements on days 21 and 23 but nothing happens on day 22, which means that I need to have sales=0 on that day or in other words a row like this:
[Image of Row missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBmiu.png)

How can I generate the matrix needed to create the hts object? Do I need to create the missing rows with 0? (I have thousands of missing rows, so it would be a nightmare to do it by hand)

Here is a reproducible example:

```
date=c("2019-03-22","2019-03-23","2019-04-24","2019-03-25")
id_supermarket=c(4,4,2,2)
id_product=c(187,187,189,190)
id_label=c("a","a","c","d")
sales=c(21,22,23,24)

df=as.data.frame(cbind(date,id_supermarket,id_product,id_label,sales))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use the `fable` package instead of `hts`. It is more recent and much easier to use. Here is an example with your data.

library(tsibble)
    library(fable)

```r
# Create tsibble
df <- tibble(
  date = lubridate::ymd(c("2019-03-22", "2019-03-23", "2019-03-24", "2019-03-25")),
  id_supermarket = as.character(c(4, 4, 2, 2)),
  id_product = c(187, 187, 189, 190),
  id_label = c("a", "a", "c", "d"),
  sales = c(21, 22, 23, 24)
) %>%
  as_tsibble(index = date, key = c(id_supermarket, id_product, id_label)) %>%
  fill_gaps(.full = TRUE)

# Forecast with reconciliation
fc <- df %>%
  aggregate_key(id_supermarket * id_label, sales = sum(sales, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  model(
    arima = ARIMA(sales)
  ) %>%
  reconcile(
    arima = min_trace(arima)
  ) %>%
  forecast(h = "5 days")

fc
#> # A fable: 45 x 6 [1D]
#> # Key:     id_supermarket, id_label, .model [9]
#>    id_supermarket id_label .model date       sales .distribution
#>    <chr>          <chr>    <chr>  <date>     <dbl> <dist>       
#>  1 2              c        arima  2019-03-26  5.82 N(5.8, 44)   
#>  2 2              c        arima  2019-03-27  5.82 N(5.8, 44)   
#>  3 2              c        arima  2019-03-28  5.82 N(5.8, 44)   
#>  4 2              c        arima  2019-03-29  5.82 N(5.8, 44)   
#>  5 2              c        arima  2019-03-30  5.82 N(5.8, 44)   
#>  6 2              d        arima  2019-03-26  6.34 N(6.3, 46)   
#>  7 2              d        arima  2019-03-27  6.34 N(6.3, 46)   
#>  8 2              d        arima  2019-03-28  6.34 N(6.3, 46)   
#>  9 2              d        arima  2019-03-29  6.34 N(6.3, 46)   
#> 10 2              d        arima  2019-03-30  6.34 N(6.3, 46)   
#> # … with 35 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>